# Creating and accessing global state with plpgsql procedures

Tags: postgresql

I'd like to call a custom EVAL function from within postgres to a redis instance (so I'm not sure if redis_fdw will work in this case.)

The other option is to use `plpython` with a redis library
https://pypi.org/project/redis/.

```py
import redis
r = redis.Redis(host='localhost', port=6379, db=0)
r.evalsha(<SHA>, <ARGS>)
```

I'd like to be able to create a redis pool so that each call to redis doesn't have to reestablish a connection. Is there any way to set some sort of global state within postgres itself so that a pool can be initiated on the first call and then subsequent calls just use the pool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

redis_fdw only mentions support for a handful of built-in data structures, so it doesn't look like much help for an `EVAL`.

A global connection pool will probably not be easy. Postgres runs each connection in its own server process, and you can't pass anything between them without allocating it in shared memory (which I don't see a PL/Python API for, so I think it'd need to be done in C).

But if you can afford to create one Redis connection per Postgres connection, you should be able to reuse it across PL/Python calls by putting it in a [shared dictionary](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpython-sharing.html):

> The global dictionary `SD` is available to store private data between repeated calls to the same function. The global dictionary `GD` is public data, that is available to all Python functions within a session; use with care.

So, something like

```
if 'redis' not in SD:
  SD['redis'] = redis.Redis(host='localhost', port=6379, db=0)
SD['redis'].evalsha(<SHA>, <ARGS>)
```

Comment: What's the difference between storing the connection in SD as opposed to GD?

Comment: @zcaudate: It sounds like each PL/Python function gets its own `SD`, while they all share the same `GD`. So if you wanted to share a Redis connection across multiple functions, you could put it in `GD` instead.

Comment: I'll give that a go and let you know. Thanks for your help!

Comment: GD does as expected. variables are saved across sessions. It's very useful.